# The result from getRotation is not precise in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation

Nexus 4.

I specially use System.out.println to print out the rotation on LogCat, to observe the value when I rotate my device.

```
int orientation_photo = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
System.out.println("For Debug: orientation_photo: " + orientation_photo);
```

The rotation (0, 1, 2 or 4) is not prcise at all. Sometimes I have rotated 90 degrees, but the rotation value does not change.

However,  believe Nexus 4 device can detect it correctly, from the orientation performance of its default camera, which always record a correct orientation, so that we can view pictures in a correct way.

I need a correct rotation value, so that I could put in ExifInterface of the photo .jpg file.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I find the answer, that is: Yes, it is not precise, from the basic physical principle, because the orientation is subjective.

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching the orientation of the UI, not the orientation of the phone itself.  For various reasons they do not always match.  In particular, many devices will never rotate their UI 180 degrees.

You probably want to look at the `SensorManager` class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

Comment: Thanks. Is there any built-in function to get the orientation (4 values, only) of the device?

Comment: No. Here is an example of how to use the orientation vector sensor:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978372/type-rotation-vector-not-working-on-certain-devices